# How to change the value of an Input control when the text of another Input control is changed?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

I need the following output as shown in the gif below.
I created three inputs which I put in the box below. How can I have such output?
Please help with an example

**NOTE:Suppose we have 50 inputs and the class is the same
I can't use it after Get ID**

[image]

> MY HTML code

```
  <span class="pricing-heading">Your sale price:</span><div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-set-price" type="number" value="24.00"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
                          <span class="pricing-heading">Product base Cost:</span><div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-base-price" type="number" value="10.00" disabled></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
                          <span class="pricing-heading">Your profit:</span><div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-profit" type="number" value="14.00" disabled></div>
                        </div>
```

JS code :

```
 $(".pricing-set-price").change(function(){
    var item_rrp = $(this).val();
    var item_base = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.pricing-base-price').val();
    var profit = item_rrp - item_base;
    var profit_format = profit.toFixed(2);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.pricing-profit').val(profit_format);
  });
```

Comment: `do not be bored` ??? A code attempt (from you) means you care as much as we may attempt to care. Its a demonstration of good faith.

Comment: @Swati it's working for me on Chrome browser but not on Safari

Comment: @sonali Not working on chrome :D

Comment: Please ex[lain your NOTE

Comment: I used the method you said, but the problem is that we have dozens of inputs. See the following link: http://alomykar.ir/qw
When we change the value of SalePrice in the second and third inputs and the other inputs whose idea is SalePrice, the profit of the first input changes, which is not correct.@sonali

Comment: @cdk did you solve this issue ?

Comment: No, unfortunately the problem is not solved @Swati

Answer (score 1):

You may try like

```
 $(".pricing-set-price").change(function(){
    let  currentValue = $(this).val();
    
    var previousValue = this.defaultValue;
    
    if(previousValue < currentValue){
        this.defaultValue = currentValue;
        console.log('Increment');
    }else{
        console.log('Decrement');
    }
    
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function that changes the value of Profit (input) on the onchange , oninput, or onClick **events** of the SalePrice(input)

```js
function increment() {     document.getElementById('salePrice').stepUp();
calculateProfit()
   }
   
function decrement() {
      document.getElementById('salePrice').stepDown();
      calculateProfit()
   }

function calculateProfit(){
  let sp = document.getElementById("salePrice").value;
  document.getElementById("profit").value = sp - 10;
}
```

```html
<input id="salePrice" type=number value=10 min=10 max=110 />
<button onclick="increment()">+</button>
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
<br/>
Base Price :: <input type="text" id="basePrice" value=10 
disabled >
<br/>
Profit :: <input type="text" id="profit" value=0 />
```

For more info about:

**stepUp()**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/stepUp

**stepDown()**

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_week_stepdown.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think this might help. use id for your input fields.

```js
function calculateProfit(val){
                var baseCost = document.getElementById("baseCost").value;
                document.getElementById("Profit").value = (val - baseCost).toFixed(2);
            }
```

```html
<div class="prt-pricing-heading">
            <span class="pricing-heading">Your sale price:</span>
            <div class="pricing-field"><input id="SalePrice" class="pricing-set-price" type="number" value="24.00" onchange="calculateProfit(this.value);" oninput="calculateProfit(this.value)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
          <span class="pricing-heading">Product base Cost:</span>
          <div class="pricing-field"><input id="baseCost" class="pricing-base-price" type="number" value="10.00" disabled></div>
        </div>
        <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
          <span class="pricing-heading">Your profit:</span>
          <div class="pricing-field"><input id="Profit" class="pricing-profit" type="number" value="14.00" disabled></div>
        </div>
```

For More info regarding:

**oninput()**  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_oninput.asp

**onchange()** https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp

Comment: Hi, it works well, but the problem is that if we have three inputs, the values will be wrong!